# Fixed table header with scroll is not having response design

Tags: html, css

I want to have a fixed header on a table in which the scrolling works, and re-sizing response design creates a horizontal scroll

1. horizontal scroll is not working despite the overflow: auto
2. Seems that the only way I can maintain the column header and columns of the rows to stay the same width is to remove the

   ```
   display: block;
   ```

Problem with removing  "display: block; is that even though i seem to get the responsive design with less width on the page,  I no longer have a fixed header for scrolling the rows.

```
    table tbody, table thead
    {
        display: block; 
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/j9ndqetc/

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/light/

Comment: Yes, i think so    any thoughts on what i have?

Comment: @pratikwebdev - thats the most hacking of a table ive seen. Nice.

Comment: I tried to use that  , it looks bad..    https://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/j9ndqetc/2/

Comment: i did not get you. Just refer to the CSS that is used on JSFiddle it should suffice your requirement i feel. put your table inside of section and div as done in JSfiddle. Only if you are looking for quick fix.  @Cam JSFiddle is not mine. I just googled :)

Comment: My only thought though is why did they go "Content" <div> "content" shouldnt content suffice being used once..

Comment: @pratikwebdev       -    https://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/j9ndqetc/3/    I am having a hard time giving the header to look good

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php

Comment: @GlupiJas OP is looking for fixed header table with responsive design. Brian its an interesting problem i am also looking. Good learning. Till then I would suggest refer to other similar question on Stackoverflow. There are many that I found but you might need to update your table design in process.